# Is there a IsRequired property on web controls

Tags: field-controls

I'm creating a edit view inwhich a user can create a article/document. In this edit view there are some fields that are required, but I can't see where you define that a field is required.

For example in a TextField, if this TextField has to be filled in how can you check that it is when the page is saved?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the standard [ASP.NET Validation Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like the `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator />` control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="foo" runat="server"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fooValidator" ControlToValidate="foo" 
     Text="Field foo is required." runat="server"/>
```